# Magento 2 : Pass URL from Static block to PHTML

Tags: magento2, phtml, static-block

In my static block, Following is code

```
    {{block 
        class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
        template="Magento_Theme::html/homepage-blocks.phtml"
        title="Scoring &amp; Management"
        linktitle="SHOP NOW"
        link="{{store_url='parts.html'}}"
        bgimage="{{media url='wysiwyg/parts.jpg'}}" 
    }}
```

In my **homepage-blocks.phtml** I'm trying to get above data as following

```
<?php
    echo $block->getBgimage(). "<br>";
    echo $block->getTitle(). "<br>";
    echo $block->getLink(). "<br>";
    echo $block->getLinktitle(). "<br>";
?>
```

And I'm getting following output in frontend

```
Scoring & Management
{{store_url=parts.html
SHOP NOW
" bgimage="http://test.test/pub/media/wysiwyg/parts.jpg" }}
```

But instead, I want the following output

```
Scoring & Management
http://test.test/parts.html
SHOP NOW
http://test.test/pub/media/wysiwyg/parts.jpg
```

What went wrong?

Comment: what you want to actually do using image and base url?

Comment: @RohanHapani Client should pass the URL and image link in this parameters and it will be shown in frontend via template file. As he doesn't want to deal with HTML.

Comment: Please check my answer